# "... assisting emerging countries meet their development goals..." vs "... assisting emerging countries in meeting their development goals..."

Tags: gerund-vs-infinitive

1. *Her role included assisting emerging countries meet their development goals through active engagement with senior level representation from both the public and private sectors.*
2. *Her role included assisting emerging countries in meeting their development goals through active engagement with senior level representation from both the public and private sectors.*
3. *Her role included assisting emerging countries to meet their development goals through active engagement with senior level representation from both the public and private sectors.*

The first sentence does not sound natural to me. I decided to rewrite it (the second and the third). Which of the above sentences are correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Assist* cannot simply be substituted for *help,* which is why the first doesn't work. *Help* can license the omission of the particle *to* in the following infinitive verb. Both the following sentences are correct and exactly equivalent.

> Her role included helping emerging countries meet their development goals
>   Her role included helping emerging countries to meet their development goals

*Assist* does not license the omission of *to,* so your sentence 3 is correct, using *to meet.*

However, sentences (2) and (3) are different constructions; *in meeting* and *to meet* are **both** correct, and mean the same thing, just phrased differently.